# Python: Whats the easiest way to find a xml-tag by value and change another one

Tags: xml, python-2.7

i have a xml which looks like the following:

```
<books>
<book>
    <title>MyBook1</title>
    <content>any content</content>
</book>
<book>
    <title>MyBook2</title>
    <content>any content 2</content>
</book>
<book>
    <title>MyBook3</title>
    <content>any content 3</content>
</book>
```

What is the easiest way to change to content of any book if i know the title?

Currently i use etree to iterate over all books, compare the title with the title i want to change. And if i found it, i change the conent. 
But i have the feeling there should be a easier way without the need to iterate over all books just to find one.

Answer (score 0):

The "easiest" way is a bit subjective, but my preferred way is to use [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/).

ElementTree has [limited XPath support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support), but it appears good enough for what you need.

If you end up needing to use more complicated XPath, I'd suggest using [XPath in lxml](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath).

Here's an example using ElementTree...

**XML Input** (input.xml)

```xml
<books>
    <book>
        <title>MyBook1</title>
        <content>any content</content>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>MyBook2</title>
        <content>any content 2</content>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>MyBook3</title>
        <content>any content 3</content>
    </book>
</books>
```

**Python**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("input.xml")

tree.find("book[title='MyBook2']/content").text = "*** New Content ***"

ET.dump(tree.getroot())
```

**Output** (dumped to console)

```xml
<books>
    <book>
        <title>MyBook1</title>
        <content>any content</content>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>MyBook2</title>
        <content>*** New Content ***</content>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>MyBook3</title>
        <content>any content 3</content>
    </book>
</books>
```

Here's a version using lxml (same input = same output)...

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

tree.xpath("book[title='MyBook2']/content")[0].text = "*** New Content ***"

etree.dump(tree.getroot())
```